# Retrieving uploaded Blob info from a regular handler

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blobstore, webapp2

I would like to use Google's BlobStore for my GAE app.  I want the user to upload an image along with other form data.  I know I can just use `self.request.get` event from within a `BlobstoreUploadHandler` to fetch other form data.  However, I have created a subclass of appengine's generic handler (i.e. `class Handler(webapp.RequestHandler)`) that incorporates other methods I want all of my handlers to have.  Is there I way I can still have my upload handler inherit from `Handler` and still get the blob info?

Normal way to fetch blobs

```
class UploadHandler(blobstore.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
    def post(self):
        blob_info = self.get_uploads("image")
```

Way I want to fetch blobs

```
class Handler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get_logged_in_user(self):
         #check cookie and session data
         return username

class UploadHandler(Handler):
    def post(self):
        image_info = # Somehow get blobinfo
        Data = Data(title=self.request.get("name"), image=image_info)
```

Note: I don't want to make `Handler` inherit from BlobstoreUploadHandler because I use the `Handler` class for other handlers as well.

Comment: The code in BlobstoreUploadHandler is really simple, so you could just copy the get_uploads method into your own base Handler class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a mixin class which defines your special methods and use that to create handler.  You could then use the same mixin to create the upload handler...

```
class HandlerMixin(object):
    def get_logged_in_user(self):
        ...

class Handler(webapp2.RequestHandler, HandlerMixin):
    pass

class UploadHandler(blobstore.BlobstoreUploadHandler, HandlerMixin):
    def post(self):
        ...
```

<sup><sup>1</sup>Note that the [BlobstoreUploadHandler](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/ext/webapp/blobstore_handlers.py#355) is a subclass of `webapp.RequestHandler` rather than `webapp2.RequestHandler`.  I think that in *most* ways, `webapp` and `webapp2` are API compatible, but just know that if you do something funky in `HandlerMixin` which requires `webapp2` instead of just `webapp`, that method won't work in `UploadHandler`.</sup>

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't know how to inherit from multiple superclasses in Python.  I just added `BlobstoreUploadHandler` as a superclass of `UploadHandler` like you show in your syntax and it worked!

Comment: Python has some [`super`](http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/) facilities for helping with multiple inheritance, although [not everyone agrees](https://fuhm.net/super-harmful/) on how super they actually are.